# Get a custom taxonomy value and set it as Order meta data in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, orders

I have products with a custom taxonomy called "seller" that stores the sellers ID.

**My question:** 
How do I get the value to carry over to order in the backend when product is purchased?

Here what I got so far:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_seller_meta' );
function my_custom_seller_meta( $order_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $prod_id_for_seller_id = $order->get_items();
    $prod_id = $prod_id_for_seller_id['484']['product_id']);

    $seller_id = wp_get_post_terms( $prod_id, 'soldby' );

    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_seller_id_order', $seller_id );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an order can have many different items, I am not sure that this is a good solution. Anyway, there is some errors in your code.

If you custom taxonomy is "seller", why are you using "soldby" in `wp_get_post_terms()` function. The `wp_get_post_terms()` function will give you **an array** of **post terms** for the **'seller' custom taxonomy**…

Try this instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_seller_meta', 30, 1 );
function my_custom_seller_meta( $order_id ) {
    // Get an instance of the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $order_items = $order->get_items(); // Get order items
    $item = current( $order_items ); // Get the first item

    // Get custom taxonomy 'seller' array of WP_Term objects
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'seller' );
    $wp_term = reset($terms); // Get the first WP_Term
    $term_id   = $wp_term->term_id;
    $term_slug = $wp_term->slug;
    $term_name = $wp_term->name;

    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_seller_id_order', $term_slug );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

It should work

Comment: Works prefect except I had to change  $term_slug = $wp_term->slug; to  $term_slug = $wp_term[0]->slug;

Comment: @Tsea I have maid a little mistake on my code … see my update.… I should work just as yours. Thanks :)